# how to get top record from datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to get top of record by name in datalist..

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlOtherTrends" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlOtherTrends_OnItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><a href="PostDetail.aspx?CatID=<%# Eval("CATID") %>&# <%# Eval("NAME") %>"><img id="imgPost" runat="server" width="70"></a>
                    <span><a href="PostDetail.aspx?CatID=<%# Eval("CATID") %>&# <%# Eval("NAME") %>"><asp:Label ID="lblPostName" runat="server"></asp:Label></a></span></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

now this is the list page..

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlPost" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlPost_OnItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <article>
                        <h1><asp:Label ID="lblPostName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h1><a name="<%# Eval("NAME") %>"></a>
                        <span class="posted">Posted on <asp:Label ID="lblPostDate" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> by <a href="#">Editor</a></span>
                        <p><img id="imgPost" runat="server" width="540"></p>
                        <p><div id="DivDescr" runat="server"></div></p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
                            <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like"<%="fb:like:layout"%>="button_count"></a>
                            <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
                            <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone"<%="g:plusone:size"%>="medium"></a>
                            <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4fc6ff7e30646c29"></script>
                        <!-- AddThis Button END -->
                    </article>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

by clicking of imgPost and lblPostName i need the same record in second one....the problem is all the records are coming in same page but i want to show selected one first

Comment: *Sort* your dataSource in *desc* order by *name*.

Comment: by clicking of imgPost and lblPostName i need the same record in second one....the problem is all the records are coming in same page but i want to show selected one first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top name from urdataTable desc
```

this will do if you are working with sql server